# sum up sub-report data and show in main report

Tags: pentaho

I'm using Pentaho Report Designer. I want to sum up the sub-report data and show it to my main report. Can it be possible?
If possible, how to make it.

Example : total0 is sum of month1,month2,month3...month12

Main Report: total0

Sub-report: month1 month2 month3...month12

Answer (score 3):

yes, however your subreport must execute and display first.  The trick is just to add an itemSumFunction inside the subreport, and then pass that back to the main report via a parameter ( click on parameters inside the subreport and make sure it is added to the "export" parameters list.

Comment: I am also looking for a monthly report in a given time period.  However, I am very new to Pentaho reporting.  (So far, I just did one normal report only.)  Can you please guide me with one example of **Sub-reports** OR please explain it more here.  Thanks in advance.